# How can I perform multiple processes simultaneously in Python (on Jetson Nano or any computer?)

Tags: python, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have a Jetson Nano and I'm going to build a mobile robot. I want to control the wheels using PWM signals, use a Lidar sensor to scan the area, and use OpenCV to have an AI running that can track and follow me. My question is, how can I perform all these tasks (almost) simultaneously, reducing the latency between processes and making it as optimized as possible? I'm not asking for code, just a guide on how I could approach this, what paradigm to use, whether to use asynchronous processes or multiprocessing, things like that.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: This question is too broad. You should at least restrict your question to be about a single approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should look at async libraries at python. Such as asyncio, and trynna to built a code with it. Or multithreading libraries :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).